# Can I run the emulator without HAXM

Tags: windows-7, android

I'm creating android app. My computer does not support Intel VT-x. So I'm unable to Install HAXM.exe on my system and unable to run my app.

What would be best way to proceed further?
How can i run the emulator without HAXM.exe installed in my laptop?

Answer (score 4):

The default software emulator runs with or without HAXM.  Intel HAXM just adds hardware capabilities to speed up the emulation.

Answer (score 3):

You can download and use `ARM images` if you want to run emulator without HAXM.

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: I am unable to find where from I can download these images...

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. It seems that the emulator from Android SDK Tools 23.0.5 requires hardware acceleration, regardless if you choose it or not.

They say that GENYMOTION wouldn`t help either, because it also needs hardware acceleration. The option is to build and emulate for ARM.

More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455756/how-can-i-run-android-emulator-for-intel-x86-atom-without-hardware-acceleration